# private static final String not doing its job

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have implemented a global private static final string Key like this:

```
private static final String KEY_STUFE = "Stufe";
```

To use it with [EasyPreferences.](https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPreferences/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/pixplicity/easyprefs/library/Prefs.java)

When I type a hardcoded String like

```
int abc = Prefs.getInt("MyKey", 1);
```

The code works fine.

But when I use the global key:

```
int abc = Prefs.getInt(KEY_STUFE, 1);
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer

I do not get the error. The global key is defined as a String and the functions expects a string. So fine so good. 
So why do I get such an error?

Comment: Have you tried setting `KEY_STUFE = "MyKey"`?  The likelihood is that it's intentionally throwing the `ClassCastException` since the value of `"Stufe"` isn't something that can be matched to an int.

Comment: Based on the 3 lines of code in your question, I don't see how this could be happening.  There must be some difference you're not including.  Can you provide the full class that can reproduce this error?

Comment: Well, how to tell you... `"Stufe"` is different from `"MyKey"`.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the `getInt` method:

> Throws
>      ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not
>      an int.

This is most likely what happens here, the key `"Stufe"` does not have an int value associated.

Comment: That is possible. Is there a possibility to delete those previous prefs that I do not need anymore ?

Comment: You can use the "clear data" button in settings -> apps